# Aligning list to the right side of div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align ul items inside a div which happens to also contain a logo. The logo is nicely aligned all the way to the left of its 66% wide containing div but I can't seem to smash the ul to the right. It get's stuck before social icons as depicted on the screenshot below, while it is supposed to be underneath them.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Racih.png)

HTML

```
 <div class="nav-header">
        <div class="nav-header-container">

            <!-- LOGO -->
                <a class="logotina" href="#0">
                    <img src="kormosilogo.png" alt="kormosi"
                    class="logo-image">
                </a>

            <!-- MAVIGATION BUTTONS --> 
                <ul class="navigation-buttons-list">
                    <li><a href="#0">portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#0">kontakt</a></li>               
                </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.nav-header {
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #4D4D4D;
}

.nav-header-container {
    width: 66%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 80px;
}


.logo-image {
    height: 3em;
    padding: 15px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    float: left;

}

.logo-image:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
}

.navigation-buttons-list {
    font-family: 'Roboto Black', sans-serif;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 35px;
    padding: 15px;
}

.navigation-buttons-list li{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navigation-buttons-list a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #D2D2D2;
    padding: 18px
}
```

All tips will be highly appreciated.

Comment: provide more codes so that we can remake the screenshot....

Comment: Hi. There is 2 closing divs here. please put the opening tags so we can see the classes.

Comment: Here you go.  http://codepen.io/patres/pen/amadGV

Comment: Deleted my answer as my suggestion didn't solve the main issue. Your CSS is quite messy, with paddings and font sizes not adding up, so I cleaned up your codepen a little, like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qarbJY?editors=1100 Does it now look more how you expect?

Comment: You are the best. I've been into web development for three weeks now, so i admit that my code might not be the cleanest yet. Thank you for answer and have a nice day!

Comment: Update: Your solution seemed to work perfectly in your codepen, but not so in my css. So I tried, out of pure desperation, to remove lines linking reset.css and normalize.css from my html and voilá, everything worked perfectly. Thanks again for your participation.